# Jetpack Compose offset image vector in Canvas

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a problem with vector image in `Canvas`. As shown below I can just call vector image but I can’t make any offset in `Canvas`. So I only can have it the way it is.

I don't know the reason why there is no `Offset` option like in `drawCircle` or `drawRect`, if someone has some ideas it would be great.

```
val vector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_test)
val painter = rememberVectorPainter(image = vector)

Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
            with(painter) {
                draw(
                    painter.intrinsicSize
                )
            }

        }
    }
```

I tried something like adding Offset into `with(painter)` but nothing changes:

```
with(painter) {
    draw(
        painter.intrinsicSize
    )
    Offset(x = 10f, y = 10f)
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`DrawScope.translate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/package-summary?hl=vi#(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope).translate(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Function1)):

```
translate(left = 10f, top = 10f) {
    with(painter) {
        draw(
            painter.intrinsicSize
        )
    }
}
```